# Use of value-of tag for specifying custom coloured hyperlinks

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with the following snip of old code which allows for custom specified hyperlink colours. When upgrading the application from current 32 bit to 64 bit, the 64 bit version is stricter in enforcing validation rules and the xsl doesn't want to present the same way.

I've tried cleaning the code up, which allowed me to narrow the issue down to the use of tags. Which I assume is due to the stricter validation, I'm just not sure how to rework it so we retain the custom coloured hyperlinks after upgrading.

Original code that works on an old version of a 32 bit parser

```
A:visited{ color: Blue; }   

    A#actionHyperlink{ 
<xsl:text>color: #</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/hyperlinkActionColour"/>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>                  padding-right: 5px;
                 }

A#dataHyperlinkNoPadding{ 
<xsl:text>color: #</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/hyperlinkDataColour"/>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>}
```

Checked and the following works in the 64 bit version of the parser

```
a:visited{ color: Blue; }

a#actionHyperlink{ color: Green; padding-right: 5px; }

a#dataHyperlinkNoPadding{ color: Orange; }
```

but as soon as a tag is included, like

```
a:visited{ color: Blue; }                    

a#actionHyperlink{ 
     <xsl:text>color: Green;</xsl:text> 
      padding-right: 5px; }     

a#dataHyperlinkNoPadding{ color: Orange; }
```

the XSL seems to take the first encountered tag, in this case actionHyperlink, moves it to later in the code, and pulls all other tags into it. So because I'm trying to use value-of tags to add custom colours, I end up with one hyperlink that has ALL the value-of tags. So the XSL has lost shape and looks something like the below (and none of the hyperlinks end up with the correct custom colour)

```
a:visited{ color: Blue; }

a#dataHyperlinkNoPadding{ }

a#navigationHyperlink{ }

a#otherHyperlinkWithPadding{ padding-right: 5px; }

a#actionHyperlink{ 
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/hyperlinkActionColour"/>
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/dataHyperlinkNoPadding"/>
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/navigationHyperlink"/>
<xsl:value-of select="//mytest/systemConfig/otherHyperlinkWithPadding"/>
```

}

So should I still be able to use tags and if not, how would one code around this issue?

Comment: *"the 64 bit version is stricter in enforcing validation rules and the xsl doesn't want to present the same way"* — Uhm...what?

Comment: Sorry, just a bit hard to explain